# How to change bits into binary integer if the bits start to count from left to right in C#?

Tags: c#, binary, integer, bit

I want to change the bits into a 16 bits integer in a certain position but the position of the bits its given from left to right. How to do it ?

Here is an example: I have to change the bits in given position to "1".

```
int a = 27991; // binary its "01101101 01010111"
int position1 = 12; // this position means i have to change "01101101 0101**0**111"
int position2 = 1; // this position means i have to change "0**1**101101 01010111"
```

I hope you understood me and someone can help a little.

Comment: `int` is a shortcut to `System.Int32`, which is a signed 32 bit integer... use `ushort` instead ;)

Comment: [Masks and flags using bit fields in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6792/Masks-and-flags-using-bit-fields-in-NET)

Comment: Your convention is also backwards.  The MSB is always written on the left and is always assigned the highest ordinal number.  This means the bit has the same position if, say, you decide to write it as a 32-bit number instead.  In your example, the 0th bit would become the 16th bit if you decided to write this as a 32-bit number.  Just think of how little sense that makes.

Comment: See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a mask that has the leftmost bit, and then shift it right `positionX` times to make the proper mask:

```
int topBit = 1<<16; // 10000000 00000000
int mask = topBit >> position1;
```

Now you can use `mask` to set or to clear the target bit, like this:

```
int b = a | mask;  // Set 12-th bit to 1
int c = a & ~mask; // Set 12-th bit to 0
```